# How to check if a string variable begins or ends with a specific pattern?

Tags: terraform

How to implement an IF-ELSE condition that checks if a string variable *begins* or *ends* with a specific pattern, as shown in the example use-case below:

```
variable "app_version" {
  type = string
}
```

```
locals {
  var1 = ?
  # IF var.app_versions starts with "1", set to true
  # ELSE set to false

  var2 = ?
  # IF var.app_version ends in "a", set to 0.25
  # ELSE set to 1
}
```

Coming from Python, I was expecting something similar to Python's `str` functions:

- [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)
- [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduced in Terraform [**1.3.0**](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v1.3.0), there are now [`startswith`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.3.x/functions/startswith) and [`endswith`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.3.x/functions/endswith) functions.

> `startswith` takes two values: a string to check and a prefix string. The function returns true if the string begins with that exact prefix.
>
> ```
> startswith(string, prefix)
> ```

> `endswith` takes two values: a string to check and a suffix string. The function returns true if the first string ends with that exact suffix.
>
> ```
> endswith(string, suffix)
> ```

Applying that to the code in the question:

```
locals {
  var1 = startswith(var.app_version, "1")
  var2 = endswith(var.app_version, "a") ? 0.25 : 1.0
}
```

```
> startswith("1.0.0", "1")
true
> startswith("0.3.4", "1")
false

> endswith("1.0.0", "a")
false
> endswith("1.0.0a", "a")
true
```

If however you are still on Terraform **<1.3.0** and cannot upgrade, there is still [`regexall`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.2.x/functions/regexall):

> `regexall` can also be used to test whether a particular string matches a given pattern, by testing whether the length of the resulting list of matches is greater than zero.

```
locals {
  var1 = length(regexall("^1.*", var.app_version)) > 0
  var2 = length(regexall(".*a$", var.app_version)) > 0 ? 0.25 : 1.0
}
```

```
> length(regexall("^1.*", "1.0.0"))
1
> length(regexall("^1.*", "0.3.4"))
0

> length(regexall(".*a$", "1.0.0")) > 0
false
> length(regexall(".*a$", "1.0.0a")) > 0
true
```